# Loading gif in jQuery ajax call is not showing

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am sure this must be a basic error on my part - but I am completely failing to see it.

I have a jQuery UI dialog which I use to present a form to edit a record .. at the bottom of the html (which itself is loaded via ajax) it has a div containing an  (animated loading gif).  The loading div is hidden after loading the html.

The CSS puts the div in an absolute position in the bottom right corner.

When the Save button on the dialog is clicked I call a function to save the info via ajax. In the ajax call I have:

```
beforeSend: function() {
              $("#ajaxLoading").show();
        },
  complete: function() {
              $("#ajaxLoading").hide();
        }
```

The problem is that the image does not show.

If I remove the hide() after the initial dialog load, then the gif is displayed throughout.

I tried putting the show() just before the ajax call rather than in the beforeSend .. still nothing.

I tried putting the show() in the dialog setup - in the "Save" button click. Nothing.

If I put a breakpoint in the script with Chrome and step through then I DO see the gif!
So, I tried putting a couple of second timeout after the show() .. but still nothing.

I have no more ideas what to try.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions and comments ... I have got to the bottom of the problem - it was ... it was down to a combination of running ajax async and me closing the dialog at the wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps

> I had the same issue and i really don't know how it's happening, but it can
>   be fixed using a small delay in code like follows.

### solution 1

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/",
  beforeSend:function(){
    $("#ajaxLoading").show(1);
    // please note i have added a delay of 1 millisecond , which runs almost same as code with no delay.
  },
  complete:function(data){
    $("#ajaxLoading").hide();
    //here i write success code
  }

});
```

### solution 2

```
   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/",
      beforeSend:function(){

        setTimeout(function(){
           $(".loader-image").show();
        }, 1);
        // please note i have added a delay of 1 millisecond with js timeout function which runs almost same as code with no delay.
      },
      complete:function(data){
        $(".loader-image").hide();
        //here i write success code
      }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    data: 'your data',
    url: 'your url',                      
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    async:false,
    onLoading:jQuery("#ajaxLoading").html('<img src="http://example.com/images/spinner.gif" />').show(),
    success: function(data){ 
        jQuery("#ajaxLoading").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is onLoading in jQuery ajax?

Comment: @Upland when ajax is call then onLoading event is call.

Answer (score 0):

How I use and working fine scripts is...

```
$("#save_button").click(function () {
    // start showing loading...        
    $("#ajaxLoading").show();

    // make an ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function() {
            // when success, hide loading.
            $("#ajaxLoading").hide();

            // your additional scripts
            if( a == null ){
                // some script          
            }
            else{
                // some script
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the loader gif as html like this:

```
beforeSend: function() {
              $("#ajaxLoading").html('<img src="image source" />');
        },
  complete: function() {
              $("#ajaxLoading").html('')
        }
```